# Cell Fracture Deactivation not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, glass, cell-fracture

I'm currently animating a simple sequence of a character jumping through glass. I followed a tutorial using the cell fracture for the glass, but when I enable Deactivation and Start Deactivated for the glass particles, they still fall before impacted by the character.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated!

Comment: I just untick the 'Dynamic' box in one of the cell's physics.  They would normally all be linked so doing that on one should deactivate them all.
To conceal them all freezing at the same frame, one or more cell's can also be animated past the deactivation frame - continued...

Comment: ...cont.  see the Blend file and deactivation here, 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237426/how-to-animate-an-explosion-in-a-certain-direction-why-is-my-shatter-going-in-t/237617#237617

- and the (single) animated fragment and blue dot here to have them continue on a little after deactivation.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250057/double-interaction-with-cell-fracture/250431#250431